# Sendmail Centos 7 sending mail to localhost 127.0.0.1 instead of domain?

Tags: centos7, sendmail, mx-record, hostname

I know there is plenty of questions similar to do this none of them helped me out at all.

**I'd like to add that I have another domain name running on the same server called camspark.com which if I send mails to like webmaster@camspark.com I get them on my gmail account no problem, even though it's using the same sendmail, the problem is I think my box's hostname is set to highgamer.com, if I set it to anything else then sendmail doesn't work at all just freezes up.**

I could send emails to any outside domain like `test@gmail.com` and they come no problem. But when I try to send email to `test@mydomain.com` the same domain where the sendmail server is setup it doesn't get sent, it comes in locally with console `mail` command, but I recently disabled that with a few questions here.

to clear some inconsistencies.
My `/etc/mail/local-host-names` doesn't contain my domain address.
[image: pic 1]

My `sendmail.mc` which I compile using `m4` to `sendmail.cf` after the changes.
`m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`
Then reboot my sendmail service by running
`service sendmail restart`

To prevent emails coming in locally to my `mail` command in `ssh`. I added these 3 lines to my `sendmail.mc`

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `highgamer.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `highgamer.com.')dnl
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `highgamer.com')dnl
```

just above the `MAILER(smtp)dnl`

Here is a picture 
[image: pic 2]

**Here is a full sendmail analysis and problem debugging log**
As you can see it connects to localhost `127.0.0.1` instead of my MX records for that domain.

[image: pic 3]

**EDIT THE TOP PHOTO PROVES NOTHING, HERE IS CAMSPARK.COM PHOTO**
[image: pic 4]

[image: pic 5 email]
[image: pic 6 email packets]
Here is my MX settings for the same domain name.
[image: pic 7]

Answer (score 2):

The `sendmail` submission agent uses 127.0.0.1 by default. Do you even need to be running a mail server? If not, configure `sendmail` to send the command line mail elsewhere by editing up `submit.mc` to point to the desired domain:

```
dnl FEATURE(`msp', `[127.0.0.1]')dnl
FEATURE(`msp', `highgamer.com')dnl
```

Then rebuild `submit.cf`. (Without a mail server running you may need a cron job or something to clear out temporarily delivery failures to your MX, or a submission agent queue runner, depending on how you want to handle that.)

Comment: I found out the `127.0.0.1` has no problem for camspark.com domain running the same sendmail, it probably has nothing to do with that anyways. It just has a problem sending to it's own domain that the box uses.

Comment: @SSpoke and the standard advice there is never to name a system after the domain, instead call it `foo.example.com` so it is not `example.com`.

Comment: my system is just named highgamer, it's  `root@highgamer`, it's the hostname i set to `highgamer.com` if I set it to anything else it just hangs up the sendmail and never sends anything, I just tried setting it to `test.highgamer.com` it still works properly but no emails come in.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! by removing

```
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `highgamer.com')dnl
```

you may get `User unknown root` errors from postmaster delivery after this, but there is a way to fix that quickfix it I mean by adding `root@domain.com` to get forwarded to your main email in your domain register settings.